# Where is name defined in image_effect_info_alter(&$effects)?

Tags: 7, hooks, media

```
function my_module_name_image_effect_info_alter(&$effects) {
    $effects += array(
        'whatever' => array(
            'label' => t('blabla'),
            'help' => t('Everything you need to know about this effect'),
            'effect callback'=> 'function_I_wrote',
            'dimensions callback'=> 'another_function_I_wrote',
            'form callback'=> 'image_resize_form', //This one is sufficient
            'summary theme'=> 'image_resize_summary', //No need for own summary
            'module'=> 'image', //dunno?
            'name'=> 'image_rotate', //this is where my question is about
            'data'=> []
        )
    ); 
}
```

So I was looking at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.api.php/function/hook_image_effect_info/7

They don't even mention name, but without it I get error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name'
>   doesn't have a default value

And if I specify my own name it doen't show up under the Image styles effect section after adding. Using an existing one gives it that name. So my guess it's some kind of constant. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: I think the alter method should not exist if this is the easier way.

Call `hook_image_effect_info()` and just pass

> label, help, effect callback, dimension callback and form callback

this way it won't ask for

> name